# How to transform nested JSON to CSV with Flatten?

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, export-to-csv

**Updated question:**

[@CarstenMassmann 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77818046/1113256) is working fine for me but I need next level solution for multiple data. Now, my data looks like this

```
const dataExam1 = [{"name": "Raghav","standard": "I","marks": [{"subject": "Maths","grade": "A1", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Science","grade": "B", "result":"Pass"}]},{"name": "Isha","standard": "II","marks": [{"subject": "Science","grade": "A", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Maths","grade": "B1", "result":"Pass"}]}],
      dataExam2 = [{"name": "Raghav","standard": "I","marks": [{"subject": "Maths","grade": "A", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Science","grade": "B1", "result":"Pass"}]},{"name": "Isha","standard": "II","marks": [{"subject": "Science","grade": "C", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Maths","grade": "D", "result":"Pass"}]}],
```

I want the same result as previous but it should contains more columns for subject, grade and result, for both exam1 and exam2. Thank you.

Expected result:
[image]

---

*Previous question:*

I am trying to export JSON data to csv / excel by using exceljs library. My data has nested objects and I want to trasnform nested objects to columns.

I have this JSON data

```
[
  {
    "name": "Raghav",
    "standard": "I",
    "marks": [
      {
        "subject": "Maths",
        "grade": "A1",
        "result": "Pass"
      },
      {
        "subject": "Science",
        "grade": "B",
        "result": "Pass"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Isha",
    "standard": "II",
    "marks": [
      {
        "subject": "Maths",
        "grade": "B1",
        "result": "Pass"
      },
      {
        "subject": "Science",
        "grade": "A",
        "result": "Pass"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here's the code to export JSON data to csv

```
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');

// excel export start
let workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook()
let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('marks')
worksheet.columns = [

    { header: 'Name', key: 'name' },
    { header: 'Surname', key: 'surname' },
    { header: 'Marks', key: 'marks' },
]

worksheet.getRow(1).font = { bold: true }

async function exportToExcel() {

    console.log('exportToExcel called');
    let queryExport = query(collectionGroup(db, "2023-24"),
        where('year', '==', '2023-24'),
        where('exam', '==', '001'),
        orderBy('roll', "asc"),
        limit(2)
    );

// getting data from Firestore
    getDocs(queryExport)
        .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((doc, index) => {
                const rowIndex = index + 2
                let e = doc.data()
                console.log(e);
                let newEntry = doc.data();
                newEntry.name = e.name;
                newEntry.surname = e.surname;

                worksheet.columns.forEach(column => {
                    worksheet.addRow({
                        ...e,
                    })
                })
            });
            workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer()
                .then(buffer => FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([buffer]), `pcs_bkp_${Date.now()}.xlsx`))
                .catch(err => console.log('Error writing excel export', err))
        });
}
```

Above code is working properly and I am getting csv file as shown below.

[image: result achieved]

But I want to export my nested array trasformed and expected result should like below.

[image: expected result]

Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: Can you insert a `console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot))` before `snapshot.forEach(...` and share the output with us? That should be the `data` we need to work with.

Comment: Its working fine. I have added this line const data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

Now only one problem is there. This code is generating blank excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data object (it is not a JSON string but an object) contains the marks in a strange format: for the subject "Maths" they are under the key "grade" and for "Science" they are stored under "marks".

The following snippet can deal with it, but it is only a rudimentary attempt at demonstrating a CSV conversion as it will break, as soon as there is a comma involved in any of the data strings.

```js
const data=[{"name":"Raghav","grade":"I","marks":[{"subject":"Maths","grade":"A1"},{"subject":"Science","marks":"B"}]},{"name":"Isha","grade":"II","marks":[{"subject":"Maths","grade":"B1"},{"subject":"Science","marks":"A"}]}];

function gradesCSV(data) {
  return ["Name","Grade",data[0].marks.map(m=>m.subject)].join(",")+"\n"
        +data.map((d,i)=>[d.name,d.grade,...d.marks.map(m=>m.grade||m.marks)].join(",")
                 ).join("\n");
}

console.log(gradesCSV(data));
```

The above code assumes that all objects of the `marks` arrays are ordered in the same way and have the same properties. If this cannot be guaranteed then something like the following is necessary:

**2. Update** (after comment, see below)

```js
const data=[{"name": "Raghav","standard": "I","marks": [{"subject": "Maths","grade": "A1", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Science","grade": "B", "result":"Pass"}]},{"name": "Isha","standard": "II","marks": [{"subject": "Science","grade": "A", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Maths","grade": "B1", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Chemistry","grade": "D", "result":"Fail"}]}];
            
function gradesCSV(data) {
  // get all possible subjects:
  let subj = {},
    subjIdx = {},
    subArr = [];
  data.forEach(d => d.marks.forEach(m => subj[m.subject] = 1));
  // generate a subject array and an index object for the order of subjects:
  subArr = Object.keys(subj).sort(); // array of subjects, sorted alphabetically
  subArr.forEach((s, i) => subjIdx[s] = i); // map of index numbers for each subject in subArr

  return ["Name", "Standard", subArr.map(s=>[s,s+" result"]).flat().join(",")] + "\n" +
    data.map((d, i) => {
      let marks = Array(subArr.length).fill(["",""]);
      d.marks.forEach(m => marks[subjIdx[m.subject]] = [m.grade,m.result]);
      return [d.name, d.standard, ...marks].flat().join(",")
    }).join("\n");
}

console.log(gradesCSV(data));
```

**3. and 4. Update:**

In response to the two latest comments by OP I added another version of my snippet for processing multiple data objects. The latest change will now also *merge* the `marks` arrays of separate data sets whenever the `name` property of an element is the same.

After inserting the line

```
const data=[...arguments].flat();
```

at the top of the `gradesCSV()` function a `.reduce()` loop is needed for the merging process. Once the merged array `data` is created the rest of the operation can stay unchanged:

```js
const data1=[{"name": "Raghav","standard": "I","marks": [{"subject": "Maths","grade": "A1", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Science","grade": "B", "result":"Pass"}]},{"name": "Isha","standard": "II","marks": [{"subject": "Science","grade": "A", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Maths","grade": "B1", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Chemistry","grade": "D", "result":"Fail"}]}],
      data2=[{"name": "Raghav","standard": "II","marks": [{"subject": "Chemistry","grade": "B1", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "English lit.","grade": "A", "result":"Pass"}]},{"name": "HarryPotter","standard": "I","marks": [{"subject": "Science","grade": "A", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Maths","grade": "B1", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Wizardry","grade": "A", "result":"Pass"}]}];
            
function gradesCSV() {
  const data=Object.values([...arguments].flat().reduce((a,{name,standard,marks})=>{
    const m=(a[name]=a[name]||{name,standard}).marks=[];
    m.push(...marks);
    return a;
  },{}));
  // get all possible subjects:
  let subj = {},
    subjIdx = {},
    subArr = [];
  data.forEach(d => d.marks.forEach(m => subj[m.subject] = 1));
  // generate a subject array and an index object for the order of subjects:
  subArr = Object.keys(subj).sort(); // array of subjects, sorted alphabetically
  subArr.forEach((s, i) => subjIdx[s] = i); // map of index numbers for each subject in subArr

  return ["Name", "Standard", subArr.map(s=>[s,s+" result"]).flat().join(",")] + "\n" +
    data.map((d, i) => {
      let marks = Array(subArr.length).fill(["",""]);
      d.marks.forEach(m => marks[subjIdx[m.subject]] = [m.grade,m.result]);
      return [d.name, d.standard, ...marks].flat().join(",")
    }).join("\n");
}

console.log(gradesCSV(data1,data2));
```

In the above snippet I used the "old fashioned" `arguments` approach. In modern code you should rather use the "rest parameter syntax"

```
function gradesCSV(...args) {
  const data=args.flat();
  ...
}
```

which will achieve exactly the same.

**5. Update**

Now, that OP has posted a set of test data I prepared yet another snippet ...

The new information is that, although the results for each students need to be merged, the *actual results* for each subject refer to *different exams* and should therefore be listed in *two sets of columns*, prefixed by the name of the exam cycle (like: "Exam1_", "Exam2_" ...).

This is almost *a completely new question* and *should be posted as such in SO*. However, I will have a go at it here nonetheless.

The following snippet is therefore a **complete rewrite**, using the Papaparse library for the CSV conversion.

```js
const dataExam1 = [{"name": "Raghav","standard": "I","marks": [{"subject": "Maths","grade": "A1", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Science","grade": "B", "result":"Pass"}]},{"name": "Isha","standard": "II","marks": [{"subject": "Science","grade": "A", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Maths","grade": "B1", "result":"Pass"}]},{"name": "Carsten","standard": "I","marks": [{"subject": "Maths","grade": "B", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Science","grade": "B", "result":"Pass"}]}],
      dataExam2 = [{"name": "Raghav","standard": "I","marks": [{"subject": "Maths","grade": "A", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Science","grade": "B1", "result":"Pass"}]},{"name": "Isha","standard": "II","marks": [{"subject": "Science","grade": "C", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Maths","grade": "D", "result":"Pass"}]}],
      dataExam3 = [{"name": "Raghav","standard": "I","marks": [{"subject": "Maths","grade": "A", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Science","grade": "B1", "result":"Pass"}]},{"name": "Isha","standard": "II","marks": [{"subject": "Science","grade": "C", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Maths","grade": "D", "result":"Pass"}]},{"name": "Carsten","standard": "I","marks": [{"subject": "Maths","grade": "A", "result":"Pass"},{"subject": "Science","grade": "A", "result":"Pass"}]}];

function exams2CSV(...data){
 const res={};
 data.forEach((da,i)=>{
  da.forEach(({name,standard,marks})=>{
   let r=res[name]=res[name]||{name,standard};
// or, even shorter: ;-)
// let r=res[name]??={name,standard};
   marks.forEach(({subject,grade,result})=>{
    let s=`Exam${i+1}_${subject}`;
    r[s]=grade;
    r[s+"_result"]=result;
   });
  });
 });
 return Papa.unparse(Object.values(res));
}

document.querySelector("pre").textContent=exams2CSV(dataExam1,dataExam2,dataExam3)
```

```html
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/papaparse@5.4.1/papaparse.min.js
"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

In order to show the versatility of the function I added a third data array (`dataExam3`) and sneaked my "own" results in there. Now there are three blocks of results columns ("Exam1", "Exam2" and "Exam3").

**6. Update (answer to question in comment)**

What does the following line do?

```
   let r=(res[name]=res[name]||{name,standard});
```

The expression inside the parantheses is an assignment to the array element `res[name]`. Should this element already exist then exactly this element will be (re-)assigned to itself again, otherwise the `||` (or) operator will cause the second expression (an object constant) to be evaluated and assigned instead. It turns out that the parantheses aren't really necessary after all (I deleted them in the actual code now). After the pre-existing or the new value is assigned to `res[name]` a second assignment is done to the variable `r`. You can think of this variable as a "shortcut" to the target object behind the slightly longer reference `res[name]`. I use `r` later on to assign some property values to this object.

An even shorter alternative to the above expression can be written with the "[nullish coalescence assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)" `??=`:

```
let r=res[name]??={name,standard};
```

This means, that if the variable already exists and has a "non-nullish" value (an object is always non-nullish) it will be assigned to itself, otherwise the expression *behind* the operator will be assigned instead. The result is exactly the same as in the first version using the or (`||`) operator

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again @CarstenMassmann but I am thinking to add one more field to my nested object `marks` and want this newly added field. Can you help me?

[{
    "name": "Raghav",
    "standard": "I",
    "marks": [
      {
        "subject": "Maths",
        "grade": "A1",
        "result": "Pass"
      },
      {
        "subject": "Science",
        "grade": "B",
        "result": "Pass"
      }
    ]
  }]

How can I get field `result` from marks field?

Comment: Which is the new "field" (we usually talk about "properties" of objects)? The example you posted in your comment contains the same properties as your original post ... ("grade" has now become "standard").

Comment: Yes actually I mistakenly posted wrong field name that's why I corrected the same. Now I have a field named "result" which is available under "marks" nested object. And I want to export it to csv as this order "name, standard, maths, maths.result, science, science.result.

Thank you.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you change your original question by editing the the actual post of the question instead of communicating the changes in some difficult to find comment. I have adjusted my answer nonetheless ;-) .

Comment: Thanks @CarstenMassmann. I also updated my original question. Thank you very much for your outstanding help.

Comment: Hello @CarstenMassmann, I have one more query on the same question. I have multiple data (in similar format but only subjects and grade are different). How can I export all data? 

I tried to paste sample data but stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post too many texts.

Comment: Well, you are encouraged to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your SO post. This _can_ easily be several hundred lines of text but you should of course limit it to the minimum. Only post as much as is necessary to illustrate the complexity of a question. Apparently, there is a limit of 30000 characters per question post.

Comment: Is it possible to implement your solution with multiple data? (Two different JSON objects in this example like data1 and data2?

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I have two different data source for same students i.e. Raghav and Isha in my example. Just subject and grade are different. FYI: Two different data is two different exams (students are same). Thank you

Comment: It is always best to present us with an MCVE and that would have included some sample data too. Doing it this way saves time and effort for everyone involved.

Comment: Thanks @CarstenMassmann, your updated solution (5th) is really very very helpful. I have no words for this solution. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Hello @CarstenMassmann, can you explain this line? let r=(res[name]=res[name]||{name,standard}); I mean what is the use of res[name]=res[name]?

Comment: Hi @CarstenMassmann, your provided solution is working like a charm in my case. Can you please help me to export subject in desired order? I want to export it in certain order i.e. first subject must be English, second should Science, third should Social and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @CarstenMassmann, I found the solution myself :) I search the net and find the answer that Papa parse library has option like this 

`Papa.unparse({
fields: ["English", "Science", "Social"],data: Object.values(data)
})`